# Ruby on rails text_field confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have two lines

```
<%= f.text_field(:email, class: 'new_user_info', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email') %>
<%= f.text_field(:email_confirmation, class: 'new_user_info', autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email Confirmation') %></td>
```

On http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html, it states that you can use the

```
confirmation: true
```

property with the following format

```
<%= text_field :person, :email %>
<%= text_field :person, :email_confirmation %>
```

I need the confirmation to work with the first format that I stated. However, I am unable to do so. When I add the confirmation: true property it is ignored by the validator. Could someone please tell me how to validate the fact that both emails are the same with Ruby on Rails using the first set of text_field tags that I gave?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this instead

```
validates_confirmation_of :email
```

Comment: I figured out the problem, the issue was that in the params required to save I needed to include:      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :email_confirmation, :password_digest, :password_digest_confirmation). So although :email_confirmation is not in the database I still needed to include it in the params for validation